# Can I access ios IDFA using Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova-3

Cordova allows access to device UUID using:

```
var deviceID = device.uuid;
```

I am interested in accessing the advertisingIdentifier on the iOS platform.

Is the Cordova method above sufficient for this?
If not am I able to insert other code into the framework to accomplish this task (what might that look like)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Cordova doesn't ship with that specific functionality.
You will need a cordova plugin like this: https://github.com/aquto/cordova-plugin-AppleAdvertising (Apple)
I couldn't, however, make the above plugin work for myself.

Comment: The fix for that plugin is to do this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014338/adding-iad-framework-and-adsupport-framework-to-build-phases-xcode-6