# Adding iAd Framework and AdSupport Framework to Build Phases - Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6, iad

How, in Xcode 6, can I add the iAd Framework and AdSupport Framework to Build Phases? I went to the Build Phases page, but my only options are to add: "New Copy Files Phase", "New Run Script Phase", and "New Headers Phase". Which of those do the frameworks I want to input fall under, and how do I input those frameworks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should click on the Project Icon on the left. Make sure your target is selected. On the screen you should now have 6 titles in the menu (General, Capabilities, Info, Build Settings, Build Phases, Build Rules). Click on General. On linked Frameworks and Libraries ad the iAd framework.

Hope that helps.